# Repeat and insert directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 3 different directives, `<one>`, `<two>`, `<three>`.

I want to loop through their ids and insert them in an ng-repeat

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="panel in panels">
        <panel>
            <!-- panel.id would give me "one", "two" etc. -->
            <!-- First insert <one> then <two> etc -->
        </panel>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The resulting html I would like to achieve then would be:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <panel>
            <one></one>
        </panel>
    </li>
    <li>
        <panel>
            <two></two>
        </panel>
    </li>
    <li>
        <panel>
            <three></three>
        </panel>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And since each has its template:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="panel">
            <div id="one">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="panel">
            <div id="two">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="panel">
            <div id="three">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure how to do this? Is this possible? do I have to `ng-compile` to have a directive inside a directive?

Should I use just one directive and use an `ng-switch`?

Am I missing a more straightforward approach?

I know this works:

make a `<panel-content>` directive.

I include this on the `<panel>` directive:

make an

```
<ng-switch="panel.id">
    <ng-switch-when="one">
    <ng-switch-when="twp">
    <ng-switch-when="three">
</ng-switch>`
```

But it seems cumbersome.

Comment: How different are those directives - completely?

Comment: Can you show me your `panels` detail

Comment: @JonEgerton yes, for the sake of the question yes, completely.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I can't show you the actual code. But it has nothing special, a normal directive. please tell me more in detail if there's a doubt of something that can affect your answer.

Comment: Does each `<panel>` need to render three `<li>` or the issue is just that depending of which id it has you want to compile one directive or another?

Comment: @EduardoPaez I don't really understand what you're asking, each panel one `<li>` and with each time you have to use a the same `panel` inside and a different directive depending on the id of the panel being iterated.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you the solution posted by @TwitchBronBron

Answer (score 2):

The way that I normally do this is use one directive that picks the specific directive in the link function. That prevents all of the ng-switch bloat.

#### html

```
<panel type='one'></panel>
<panel type='two'></panel>
```

#### js

```
angular.module('app').directive('panel', ['$compile', '$injector', function ($compile, $injector) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, vm) {
            var template;
            switch($scope.type){
                case 'one':
                    template = '<one></one>';
                    break;
                case 'two':
                    template = '<two></two>';
                    break;
            }
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())($scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's a fiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/7cufjqs3/1/

Comment: This is interesting, let me see how it applies to my actual code and I'll get back at you.

Comment: I do think this is a good solution but the HTML is now harder to read because you hide the switch inside a directive instead of writing it in the HTML.

Comment: I'm wondering if for performance reasons it is better to add the switch in a post link function? What do you think? compile : function () { return { post : \\ your switch function \\ }}

Comment: The main reason for not using the ng-switch is that I'm pretty sure that it will create more watchers. So if you are not planning on switching the type of control to be created on the fly then there should be less memory usage doing it via the link function, which is is only run once. But you are right, it does make the html slightly harder to read.

Comment: @StefanvandeVooren I believe that the post link function and the plain old link function are one and the same. See this post from Ben Nadel. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2746-the-post-link-function-is-the-link-function-in-angularjs-directives.htm

Comment: @TwitchBronBron Thanks for pointing out the link and post link function. I didn't know. I agree with you about the watchers. It will create 1 watcher extra for each panel. For me this is a hard point in Angular. Doing it the best Angular way is most often not the best performance solution (same for a ng-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to live with an extra div between your directive and `panel` element I created a dynamic directive that knows nothing about the name of the element, and creates it dynamically:

**Usage**:

```
<li ng-repeat="panel in panels">       
    <panel>
       <dynamic-directive element="panel.id"></dynamic-directive>
    </panel>
</li>
```

**Directive**:

```
myApp.directive('dynamicDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div></div>",
        scope: {
            element: "="
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var elm = '<' + scope.element + '></' + scope.element + '>';
            element.html(elm);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12778/)

Answer (score 0):

I think a the switch is the best approach because it's most readable in your html

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="panel in panels">
        <panel ng-switch on="panel.id">
          <div ng-switch-when="one"><one>1</one></div>
          <div ng-switch-when="two"><two>2</two></div>
          <div ng-switch-when="three"><three>3</three></div>
        </panel>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ygy6coKCyQNGBoKmSES0?p=preview

Comment: That is not the desired output, should be `<panel><one></one></panel>` etc.

Comment: The output is '<li><panel><one></one></panel></li> <li><panel><two></two></panel></li>' etc... Yes there're som extra div's between the panel and the 'one' directive because of the extra switch and the extra panel directive. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the ng-switch. I actually kind of like this, thanks, I'll give it a try.